# Run SageMaker Batch transform failed on loading model

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run batch transform job with HuggineFace class and fine-tuned model and custom inference file.
The job failed on loading the model but I could load it locally.
I need to make custom inference file because i need to keep the input file as is, so i had to change the input key from the input json file.

Here are the exception :

```
PredictionException(str(e), 400)
2022-05-08 16:49:45,499 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - mms.service.PredictionException: Can't load config for '/.sagemaker/mms/models/model'. Make sure that:
2022-05-08 16:49:45,499 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 
2022-05-08 16:49:45,499 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - - '/.sagemaker/mms/models/model' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
2022-05-08 16:49:45,499 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 
2022-05-08 16:49:45,500 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - - or '/.sagemaker/mms/models/model' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
2022-05-08 16:49:45,500 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 
2022-05-08 16:49:45,500 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -  : 400
```

I am running on script mode:

```
from sagemaker.huggingface.model import HuggingFaceModel

hub = {
   # 'HF_MODEL_ID':'cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment',
    'HF_TASK':'text-classification',
    'INPUT_TEXTS': 'Description'
}

huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(model_data='../model/model.tar.gz',
                                     role=role,
                                     source_dir="../model/pytorch_model/code",
                                     transformers_version="4.6", 
                                     pytorch_version="1.7", 
                                     py_version="py36",
                                     entry_point="inference.py",
                                     env=hub
                                     )

batch_job = huggingface_model.transformer(
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.p3.2xlarge',
    output_path=output_s3_path, # we are using the same s3 path to save the output with the input
    strategy='SingleRecord',
    accept='application/json',
    assemble_with='Line'

)

batch_job.transform(
    data=s3_file_uri,
    content_type='application/json',
    split_type='Line',
    #input_filter='$[1:]',
    join_source='Input'

)
```

Custom inference.py

```
import json
import os
from transformers import pipeline
import torch
DEVICE = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'


def model_fn(model_dir):
    model = pipeline(task=os.environ.get('HF_TASK', 'text-classification'), model=model_dir, tokenizer=model_dir)
    return model

def transform_fn(model, input_data, content_type, accept):
    input_data = json.loads(input_data)
    input_text = os.environ.get('INPUT_TEXTS', 'inputs')
    inputs = input_data.pop(input_text, None)
    parameters = input_data.pop("parameters", None)

    # pass inputs with all kwargs in data
    if parameters is not None:
        prediction = model(inputs, **parameters)
    else:
        prediction = model(inputs)
    return json.dumps(
        prediction,
        ensure_ascii=False,
        allow_nan=False,
        indent=None,
        separators=(",", ":"),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the "model_data" parameter. It should point to an S3 object(model.tar.gz).

Then the transform job will download the model file from S3 and load it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is change the "task" in the pipline to "sentiment-analysis"

```
hub = {
   # 'HF_MODEL_ID':'cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment',
    'HF_TASK':'sentiment-analysis',
    'INPUT_TEXTS': 'Description'
}
```